# Git download from https://git-scm.com/download/win super slow

Tags: git, github

Whenever I try to download Git from https://git-scm.com/download/win it just downloads it with a speed of 10 kb/s and stops after around 50%..

My internet works fine, when I try to install something on steam I get my usual 2 MB/s which is still bad but not as bad as 10 kb/s... I've restarted my router, pc and used almost every browser there is. It still won't download with a normal download speed.

Can someone send a link to another trustful source?

[git download speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqDxb.png)

[steam download speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKbVp.png)

Comment: While git is a tool often used by programmers, you're not asking a programming question, which makes your question off-topic. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to avoid future issues like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look if you can download it from Download Cnet. Here is the link:

[Download Git for Windows 64-bit](https://download.cnet.com/Git-for-Windows-64-bit/3000-10247_4-77507874.html)

Comment: Thank you, I just downloaded it and cloned the current Git version.

Comment: The latest git version 2.24.1 is here: https://www.filecroco.com/download-git-for-windows/download/